# CSS on hover remove under/border-bottom

Tags: css

im wondering how to write my css so that when i hover the text the green line under the yellow box becomes yellow as well. thank you

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}

a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

link
https://jsfiddle.net/18fk9sce/

i should add that i wish the green line to remain. some solutions seem to remove the green line running across the page.

Comment: The whole green line (or) only the one under the text that is being hovered?

Comment: try this: [update_link](https://jsfiddle.net/18fk9sce/1/)

Comment: you can set other color as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML - added wrapper

```
<div class="menu__holder">
  <ul class="main_menu_left">
    <li id="left"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
    <li id="left"><a href="#Homehomehome">Homehomehome</a></li>
    <li id="left"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
    <li id="right"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
    <li id="right"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu__holder {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

ul li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

ul li:hover {
  border-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Updated fiddle - NEW](https://jsfiddle.net/76qzvves/2/)

Comment: hi, the tricky part is i want the green line to cross the page.

Comment: Hi @raskoon - changed answer to reflect full green line - see what you think - no hard coded heights

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thank you for taking the time. you separated the border in a different selector one step before. thats nice, i have to remember that. only question is:the z index, from what i read on w3school, z index -1 allows you to have something overlap, but what is the purpose of having it so high?

Comment: @raskoon Glad it helped! There's no purpose for setting it that high really apart from to keep it above the holder - it could be set lower - be careful setting z-index in minus numbers though as although you can probably see it on the page, depending on what else is on the page, users may not be able to click things in it

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've just **updated** the solution now.

Just replace the `overflow: hidden;` in `ul` with a fixed `height: 42px`. And increase the padding bottom of the **hovered** link by `2px` (i.e the `border-bottom` size). That would cover the border with yellow color of the link.

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kabirbaidhya/18fk9sce/13/)

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 42px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
```

Comment: thank for your reply good solution, but the green line doesnt run across the page anymore.

Comment: @raskoon I've just updated the solution above, it works now. Please check

Comment: This not a good solution - you're hard coding way too many things

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, thanks for replying, i've tested the css and there are some issues, such as when in your browser and you zoom in/out it does get a bit messy, if that is what you mean by hard coding too many things (ie things can break more easily?). if you have a suggestion let me know. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the border in the li not in ul, so you can separately change the border.

Just change the Style to achieve it:

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18fk9sce/1/)

**Updated Style**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;  
}
li{
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: none;//you can set other color here
}
```

Comment: And what about the border where there are no `li`s?

Comment: If he mention to keep the border under the ul then answer will be different.

Comment: @FrayneKonok yep i do wish the border to still show. sorry i didnt add that in the original post, edited now for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated CSS :- 

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
  float: left;
}

#right {
  float: right;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with adding this to your css.if this is not the case tell me

```
ul:hover{
  border-bottom:1px solid yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's just that i dont want the whole line to change color. only the small part under the yellow box.

Answer (score -1):

thanks to everyone who contributed to this question.

in the end this is the code i use.

https://jsfiddle.net/4d0ghscu/

```
<style>
.menu{
height:40px;
border-bottom:4px solid green;
padding:0;}
.menu_left{
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;}
.menu_right{
display:inline;
list-style-type:none;}
.tab_left{
float:left;}
.tab_right{
float:right;}
a{
display:block;
color:black;
padding:12px 12px;
text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{
background-color:yellow;}
</style>

<ul class="menu">
<ul class="menu_left">
<li class="tab_left"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
<li class="tab_left"><a href="#Homehomehome">Homehomehome</a></li>
<li class="tab_left"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu_right">
<li class="tab_right"><a href="#Homehome">Homehome</a></li>
<li class="tab_right"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

key to the code:
*separating left from right within an overhead. which made it simpler and more flexible to add new elements to the navigation menu.
*adding height.